# android spinner is showing hidden notification bar

Tags: android, spinner, android-notification-bar

In my app i make the app fullscreen. Means android title bar and notification bar is hidden here.
 But when i click on the spinner the hidden notification bar gets visible for fraction of seconds. It is not happening with all the spinners in my app. But where i use a array,generated by a loop execution in the spinner adapter, it is only happening in that case.
 I have come to know that it is a known bug in android. I also use the following style in spinner to resolve it.

In my app i make the app fullscreen. Means android title bar and notification bar is hidden here.
 But when i click on the spinner the hidden notification bar gets visible for fraction of seconds. It is not happening with all the spinners in my app. But where i use a array,generated by a loop execution in the spinner adapter, it is only happening in that case.
 I have come to know that it is a known bug in android. I also use the following style in spinner to resolve it.

true
     true
     @null

But still i cant solve this problem.. 
If anyone has any solution please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

add this line before setContentView():

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Then u use  `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`   in activity and it must be before of the `setContentView(....)` method

Comment: i have already used this code. I did as below..    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );      The style i have used is as below...                                          <style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="android:Theme">
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
 </style>

Comment: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
      
      setContentView(R.layout.search_page);

Comment: Here is the adapter part.........................                                            String[] str = new String[103];
         int age = 18;
         for(int i = 0; i<103; i++){
          str[i] = String.valueOf(age);
          age++;
      }
      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                 this, R.layout.spinner_item, str);
      adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  searchAgeToSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SearchAgeToSpinner);
     searchAgeToSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: The spinner part of the xml.....                                                                       <Spinner android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/SearchAgeFromSpinner" 
android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" 
android:layout_height="45dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="15dip" 
style="@style/SpinnerTheme">
</Spinner>

Comment: I have used the same spinner xml in another layout. But it is not happening there. The only difference out here is that here i am using a array using for loop..  If you can solve it please let me know.